# What does the phrase "edges the fabric" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "edges the fabric" in the following sentence:

[Depending on the look you want to go for, hold your felt sides together using a running stitch (where you stitch the thread in and out of the felt) or a blanket stitch: this is a looped stitch that **edges the fabric** as you go and adds to the homespun look and feel.](https://apps.apple.com/gb/story/id1441624778)

Comment: I assume it's the second definition of the verb [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/edge): "put a border or edge on" or "act as or be an edge of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of 'finishing' the edge of a piece of fabric is to fold it over and stitch in place to form a 'hem', however this is talking about an alternative method, where the stitching itself goes over the edge (without any folding) so that the thread prevents any fraying.